# Vertically align numbers to centered list items with fixed height

Tags: html, css

I have list items in an ordered list which have a fixed height and are vertically centered.
My problem is, that the position of the numbers is a bit off.

```css
li {
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

li > span {
  height: 80px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li><span>Some short text</span></li>
  <li><span>Some other random text which is much longer than the first one. Unfortunality all the numbers are not really aligned with the text. For longer text it's even worse, as you probably can see in this example.</span></li>
  <li><span>My number is a bit to far down there</span></li>
</ol>
```

I want the numbers to be aligned to the beginning of the text of the list item like this:
[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want the list number start from where text begin? or list number will be in the middle of the cell?

Comment: I want it to be at the beginning of the text, as shown in the picture :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use counter and rely on a negative `text-indent` to push it outside:

```css
lo {
  counter-reset: num;
}

li {
  min-height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  counter-increment: num;
  list-style:none;
}

li>span {
  height: 80px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-indent:-1em;
}

li>span::before {
  content: counter(num) ". ";
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li><span>Some short text</span></li>
  <li><span>Some other random text which is much longer than the first one. Unfortunality all the numbers are not really aligned with the text. For longer text it's even worse, as you probably can see in this example.</span></li>
  <li><span>My number is a bit to far down there</span></li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: my-awesome-counter;
}

li {
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  counter-increment: my-awesome-counter;
  position: relative;
  
}

li::before {
  content: counter(my-awesome-counter) ". ";
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: -15px;
  height: 100%;
}

li > span {
  height: 80px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li><span>Some short text</span></li>
  <li><span>Some other random text which is much longer than the first one. Unfortunality all the numbers are not really aligned with the text. For longer text it's even worse, as you probably can see in this example.</span></li>
  <li><span>My number is a bit to far down there</span></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Better than my code, but not exactly what I wanted. The number should be at the beginning of the text, as shown in the picture.